# Auth Request Headers during HTTP to HTTPS Redirects

Tags: security, http-headers

Simple question.  I would like to know when request headers are sent.  Before or after an HTTP to HTTPS redirect?  My security concern is our 3rd party vendors contacting our API with a auth-token request header if they carelessly make requests with HTTP.

Thanks for your expertise in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent that the your 3rd party vendors are sending a token over HTTP. Well, you should change the way you use the token. It shouldn't be necessary to even send it, encrypted or not.

Use the token as a pre-shared-secret. Then the authentication works as follows:

1. 3rd party vendor sends request to server, provides username or something else which identifies him to the server
2. The server sends a challenge. This is usually the application of a one-way function - a hash-function. So, the server asks the client to send a SHA1-Hash of auth-token.
3. The client solves the challenge by calculating the SHA1-Hash of auth-token. Then he sends the result back to the server.
4. The server checks the result by calculating the same SHA1-Hash of the auth-token.

Supposing that you're using a secure hash-function an attacker has no chance of stealing the token as it is only transmitted as a hash-value.

*Further reading*:
https://blog.restcase.com/restful-api-authentication-basics/